# Getting an unexpected output error as the syntax appears valid.

Tags: ruby

This code should be valid (code snippet is from a book). I am trying to learn the ruby language and I am getting an unexpected error. The author was using ruby v1.8.4 -- I am using 2.0. I suspect the version is to blame.

```
lineWidth = 40
str = '--> Word <--'

puts str.ljust lineWidth
puts str.rjust lineWidth
puts str.center lineWidth
puts str.ljust (lineWidth/2) + str.rjust (lineWidth/2)
```

**ruby version 2.0 p195**

*Error is

```
c5.rb:7: syntax error, unexpected ( arg, expecting end-of-input
puts str.ljust (lineWidth/2) + str.rjust (lineWidth/2)
```

*Output should be

```
--> Word <--
                            --> Word <--
              --> Word <--
--> Word <--                --> Word <--
```

Can someone tell me why this is returning an error? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like precedence issues, try `puts ((str.ljust (lineWidth/2)) + (str.rjust (lineWidth/2)))`, if that works try peeling off parens until you find the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the spaces between method name and parenthesis:

```
puts str.ljust(lineWidth/2) + str.rjust(lineWidth/2)
```